# Selecting UL > LI element that is populated using ng-repeat from javascript

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html-lists

I have UL>LI elements populated through angular ng-repeat. I want to select one of these LI's on click of a button that is outside ng-repeat. How can i achieve this?

Below is the sample code.

**LI list**

```html
<ul ng-controller="ConstantsController as ctrl" >
 <li ng-repeat="sectionType in sectionTypes">{{sectionType.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

**Button** - *On click of this button, particular LI needs to be selected.*

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"></button>
```

Ex:

Consider an example of LIs having A, B and C values populated through ng-repeat and on click of the button, I want B to be selected.

Comment: The object `comments` refers to a object `sectionType `?

Comment: Ok. I should have been more clear. List is in a section of page which is used to add record into the database. On adding, the added records will be displayed in a table below this section. And the edit button is in each table row. On click of this edit button, its data should be populated in the section where list is present. Hope that is clear.

Section is list item and comment is table row that contains list section.

Comment: It is still not very clear. Please give an example of arrays `comment` and `sectionTypes`. Add the explanations and examples in your question.

Comment: Hope this will help.

Consider I have a list that is populated using ng-repeat. And then I have a button (not in the list item, but in other part of my web page) clicking which a particular list item should be displayed. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Don't write an explanation in comment. Edit question by adding code of controller, full html and describe objects `comment` and `sectionTypes`.

Comment: Edited. This should be easy to understand. Not a rocket science though.

Comment: *On click of this button, particular LI needs to be selected.* What **<li>** should be selected? How to find out? They can be 100 pieces.

Comment: I have edited my post to include an example.

Comment: If you've got the right answer, mark as correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. After reading a bit of jquery API, I found following solution to be more apt.

I assign an **id** to the UL and then in javascript I use jquery **contains** function to find the LI text and change its **class** to **selected** accordingly.

**Below is the HTML/JSP Code**

```html
<ul ng-controller="ConstantsController as ctrl" id="section-type-list">
                                        <li ng-repeat="sectionType in sectionTypes" ng-click="setSection(sectionType.id, sectionType.description)">{{sectionType.description}}</li>
                                    </ul>
```

**Below is the Javascript**

```js
$("#section-type-list li:contains('" + value + "')").addClass('selected');
```

Thanks every one for your support.

Comment: Don't use `jquery` for such operation in `angular`.

Comment: Ok. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, I have given a sample since you have not provided code,

On click apply a style ,

**In HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="editComment(vote.id)" ng-class="{selected : vote.id === idSelectedVote}">
```

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.idSelectedVote = null;
$scope.editComment = function(idSelectedVote) {
   $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
   console.log(idSelectedVote);
}
```

[`DEMO APP`](http://plnkr.co/edit/82N8Mx9IusokGYuD4HxZ?p=preview)

Comment: Please refer my comment above for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-class` directive with option `isSelected` in element of array `sectionTypes`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/1rmb0qky/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.sectionTypes = [{
      description: "A",
      id: 1,
      isSelected: false
    }, {
      description: "B",
      id: 2,
      isSelected: false
    }, {
      description: "C",
      id: 3,
      isSelected: false
    }];
    vm.setSelected = function(id) {
      //Find particular element in vm.sectionTypes by id
      angular.forEach(vm.sectionTypes, function(item) {
        if (item.id === id)
          item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
      });
    };
  });
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-class="{selected:sectionType.isSelected}" ng-repeat="sectionType in vm.sectionTypes">{{sectionType.description}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-click="vm.setSelected(2)">
      set B Selected
    </button>
    <hr>
    <select ng-model="selectedSection" ng-options="sect as sect.description for sect in vm.sectionTypes">
    </select>
    <button ng-disabled="!selectedSection" ng-click="vm.setSelected(selectedSection.id)">
      set selected by select
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed UL to SELECT. Now I have model associated with it. I have a list that is populated from constants controller. Along with other details, I click on add to add all those details to the DB. Bottom part of my page has a table that displays added records. Each row of this table has an edit button. On click of this button, I want added option to be selected in my drop down. I thought binding the added option object to model would suffice, however it doesn't work. On investigation i found that the hashkey of drop down options and the one of added item is difference. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is new question. You need create new question with detailed explanation and code sample.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696298/angularjs-select-a-drop-down-option-on-button-click