# angularjs select a drop down option on button click

Tags: angularjs, select, controller, dropdown

I have a form in which there are many fields. This form is under Angular Controller, say Parent. This form has a drop down that is populated using Angular Controller, say Child. There is an **Add** button to this form on click of which all the details are stored in the DB. These added values are displayed as a row in a table below the form in the same page.

Each row of this table has **Edit** button. On click of this edit button, the values should be populated in the form above in it's respective fields. I am able to get populated all values except the drop down. I have the ng-model used for the drop down in form, set with appropriate values on click of **Edit** Button. When I click on edit, drop down options are not selected though its model object is set correctly. It still displays the first default option.

How do I get the drop down option selected?

**PN: On debugging the console, I see the hashkey of dropdown values different from the one retrieved from the table row.**

**My HTML Code for Form:**

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="ConstantsController" ng-init="listDocumentSectionTypeConstants()">
  <select class="form-control" id="section-type-list" name="section_type_list" ng-options="sectionType.description for sectionType in sectionTypes"
                                        ng-model="ctrl.comment.documentSectionTypeConstant" ng-change="$parent.setSection()" required>
    <option value=""> -- Please Select a Section --</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**My HTML Code for Button:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editComment(comment)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Comment" data-placement="bottom"></button>
```

**My Angular Controller**

```
$scope.editComment = function (comm) {        
        self.comment.documentSectionTypeConstant = comm.documentSectionTypeConstant;        
  }
```

**Note that there is no issue in add, update or delete operation.**

**EDIT** *(To include Data JSON)*

**On selecting a dropdown:**

```
Object {
     id: "DST_FOREWORD", 
     active: 0, 
     defaultSelection: false, 
       description: "Foreword", 
         showInUi: true…}
$$hashKey:"object:36"
accountNonExpired:true
accountNonLocked:true
active:0
credentialsNonExpired:true
defaultSelection:false
description:"Foreword"
enabled:true
id:"DST_FOREWORD"
showInUi:true
sortSequence:null
username:null
```

**On Click of Edit Button** *(Added Dropdown Value)*

```
Object {$$hashKey: "object:57", id: "DST_FOREWORD", description: "Foreword"}
$$hashKey:"object:57"
description:"Foreword"
id:"DST_FOREWORD"
```

Note that the hashkey are different in both the cases. Not sure if that is what the cause is.

**Edit 2**

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DakBi.png)

Comment: what is the type of comm.documentSectionTypeConstant ?? is it String?

Comment: Did you forget to add alias to your controller? ng-controller="ConstantsController", Your model is ng-model="ctrl.comment.documentSectionTypeConstant"

Comment: @Ruhul, it is an object that has id, description, etc.

Comment: @Aparna, nope. No need of alias as I have scoped elements in there.

Comment: show your data JSON that would help us to determine what's happening

Comment: @Angular_10, edited the comment to include data json.

Comment: @Maz thanks ! try the answer provided and let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using jquery. This is a definite hack. Not sure how to achieve this in angular, thus opting for jquery as of now until I find a more apt solution.

```js
$("#section-type-list option:contains('" + comm.documentSectionTypeConstant.description + "')").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

// Code

```
$scope.editComment = function (comm) {        
    self.comment={
        documentSectionTypeConstant : comm.documentSectionTypeConstant
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `ctrl.comment.documentSectionTypeConstant` is object, you can not bind your select with just string (`sectionType.description`), your ng-model should also be the object of `documentSectionTypeConstant` type.
Can you please change your ng-options as below?

```
 ng-options="sectionType as sectionType.description for sectionType in sectionTypes"
```

This should work.

Comment: It is still the same after changing it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information(less code to create) and problem statement provided in the question,I've made a  [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/uJRodaiCz78QfvJpUSIJ?p=preview) for that recreating same scenario with different example.From what I have understood from question is,you are trying to change the drop down value based on click of a button.

So in the demo example we have a dropdown containing list of phones and a text field to enter price of the phone and a button to change the value in the drop down based on the price.

In HTML

```
<body ng-controller="dobController">

    <select class="form-control" id="section-type-list" name="section_type_list"
          ng-options="item.price as item.desc for item in items" ng-model="selectedType" ng-change="setSection()" required>
        <option value=""> -- Please Select a Section --</option>
    </select>
    <input type ="text" ng-model="price"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="editComment(price)" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Comment" data-placement="bottom">Change Dropdown value</button>
</body>
```

In JS

```
$scope.selectedType = 100; //initial value to display in dropdown
        $scope.items = [{
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 4",
            "price": 100,
            "qty": 1
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 5",
            "price": 200,
            "qty": 2
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 6",
            "price": 300,
            "qty": 3
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 7",
            "price": 400,
            "qty": 1
        }];

       //on click of button set the new value..
       $scope.editComment = function(price){
           $scope.selectedType = parseInt(price);
       };
```

If you observe in HTML the way we represented the ng-options is

```
ng-options="item.price as item.desc for item in items"
```

This means that for every item in the items(list) display item's description and bind item's price in the `ng-model="selectedType"`. That's why we are setting the price to `ng-model="selectedType"` on click of button which automatically display the desired value in dropdown.

NOTE:As the item.price is integer in items,for this case we had to parse the price value as it is bind to input field ng-model as text.This care should be taken care when ever we are using numbers as ng-model as `ng-options` checks as (===).

Hope this explanation gives you some light on where you are going wrong.
In your case change ng-options to `ng-options="sectionType.ID as sectionType.description for sectionType in sectionTypes"` and in JS

```
$scope.editComment = function (comm) {        
        self.comment.documentSectionTypeConstant = comm.documentSectionTypeConstant.ID; //assuming this object contains similar data       
  }
```

Comment: For more clarity, i have added image of my screen. That should give you clear picture of what I am looking for.